# Can % location of electron on metal or ligand be negative (EPR)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy, epr-spectroscopy

Given an EPR spectrum of [Co(3-methoxysalen)(py)] :
[image: EPR spectrum of [Co(3-methoxysalen)(py)]]

and equations:

A(x) = A(iso) + B

A(z) = A(iso) - 2B

%Co in SOMO = B/B0

where A(x) and A(z) are hyperfine coupling constants measured from the spectrum and B0 = 7.6 mT, we have to calculate %Co. This is straightforward, but returns a negative percentage answer (-43%) - does this mean that there is no %Co in SOMO, or the value should be taken as an absolute and SOMO is in 43% based on the cobalt?

Thank you in advance for help.